# Send Email using C# 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to send an email but I am using asp.net c# 2.0
My server is supporting 2.0 version only. Is it possible to send email in 2.0 ?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  try
  {

   MailMessage message = new MailMessage(txtFrom.Text, txtTo.Text, txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text);
   SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(smtp.gmail.com);
   emailClient.Send(message);
   litStatus.Text = "Message Sent";

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   litStatus.Text=ex.ToString();
  }
 }
```

Comment: If your using the gmail server. You have to authenticate with the email you are sending the email from.

Comment: You need to provide credentials for SmtpClient. How do You want to send it without credentials ? Mail must be sent from some server and from some user

Comment: I tried, but with all the code I got with credentials, it is showing failure to send message

Comment: You also need to provide port

Comment: Can you please give me an example of that

Comment: If it won't work show me the error message

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this and it works nice:

```
     public static void Send()
    {
        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@ymail.com",
            "subject", "message");
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
        NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential("your_email@gmail.com", "password");

        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;
        mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
    }
```

I've also been here and turned on the access for less secure applications:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.80).aspx) SmtpClient was introduced in .NET 2.0, so you should be able to send emails in 2.0 using your code

Comment: Yes, but it shows me fail to send the email everytime with any code i try

Comment: failure to send message

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide credentials:

```
NetworkCredential _Credentials = 
new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
...

SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); // I don't know gmails port it might be 465
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
emailClient.Credentials = _Credentials;
```

EDIT.

According to exception You pasted in comments try also to add following line:

```
emailClient.EnableSsl = True;
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. s5sm3640199igh.6 - gsmtp

Comment: It's good, it means the SmtpClient class is working fine :). Check my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.80).aspx)

and select the 2.0  version.

Comment: Can you give an example of that

Comment: Sure, how about this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/163829/Sending-an-Email-in-C-with-or-without-attachments

Comment: Is it a credentials issue?